# TCP Window Update ignored

Tags: linux, tcp

My setting:

client(Browser-Firefox, Linux) ----- server(embbeded device).

1. client sends data (~1.3MB) to server
2. buffer of server runs full and responds a `window size value` of `0` to the client
3. client tries to resend with exponentially back-off time but server still responses with `window size value` of `0`
4. after a while the server tells client that new space is available by sending an empty package with `window size value` of `1436 Bytes` (Wireshark: `TCP Window Update`).
5. client ignores the `TCP Window Update` and waits to continue after the back-off time (server sent already the FIN-Flag)

Unfortunally the embedded device closes the connection after 10 seconds inactivity.

---

Wireshark-Screenshot:

[image]

---

- It also tried this with other linux devices
- It also tried with a Windows-client and this works as expected. After the client received the `TCP Window Update` it continued by sending new packages.

Does somebody can tell me what the main problem is? It seems that linux just drops theses packages.

Comment: If you have real programming code that you wrote and is exhibiting this problem, then please upldate your Q with a [mcve]  so readers can duplicate your problem. As is, this is off-topic here as it lack specficity. Please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Comment: There is not code because this is a linux stack